# adding date array values ascending in php

Tags: php, forms, input, asort

This php script generates a input-field.

```
$html_output .= '<select name="date_year" id="year_select">'."\n";
for ($year = date("Y") - 45; 
$year <= (date("Y") - $year_limit); $year++) {
$html_output .= '<option>' . $year . '</option>'."\n";
}
```

However i would like to change the $year from '2014 to 1969' instead of '1969 to 2014'.

I have found asort()-command but have failed to get it to work.

```
$html_output .= '<option>' . asort($year) . '</option>'."\n";
```

Comment: inverse it :D `$year--`

Comment: probably the best awser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be overloaded... Try this:

```
$html_output .= '<select name="date_year" id="year_select">'."\n";
$year = date("Y");
$limit = date("Y")-100;
for($i = $year; $i>=$limit; $i--){
echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
}
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/veiHi

Answer (score 2):

Look at this loop:

```
for ($i = 100; $i >= 0; $i--) { .. }
```

I guess you can see what I mean to solve your task.

Comment: I looked at your awnser but i didn't understand what you are trying to point out, sorry